# SSRS querystring one report to another report

Tags: reporting-services

I have SSRS report and i pass the URL from one report and redirect to another report secound report have some parameter and i redirect fron first report with parameter it redirecting but not assign that parameter to the text boxes of parameters can you plese help me out
sample URL

http:///Report.aspx?ItemPath=&rs:Command=Render&rp:CustomerNo=002&rp:CountryCode="123

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a subreport/ drill down report look at this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/195017/SSRS-Series-Part-II-Working-with-Subreports-DrillD) will give some clue

Comment: thank you Bhupendra for interest but My issue is different
I have 2 reports and pass URL from one report to another with parameter it redirect to another child one but its not set the value to the textbox in drill report

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea but your link is poorly formed. Your expression needs to look like this (for example, to render to PDF):

```
="http://servername/ReportServer?http://full/path/to/report/ReportName.rdl&rs%3aCommand=Render&CustomerNo=" & CStr(Fields!CustomerNo.Value) & "&CountryCode=" & Fields!CountryCode.Value & "&rs%3aFormat=PDF"
```